# How to create jar File while using another jar file?

Tags: java, jar

I'm trying to write an application  .In the app I use another jar file (opr.jar)  .In opr.jar(d:\opr.jar) I have an interface Operator  :

```
package operatorAPI;

public interface Operator
{
    int calculate(int num1 , int num2);
}
```

Also I have class Plus(d:\math\Plus) that implement Operator Interface  :

```
package math;

import operatorAPI.*;

public class Plus implements Operator
{
    public int calculate(int num1 , int num2)
    {
        return num1 + num2;
    }
}
```

In the main program(d:\source\main\Sum) I load class Plus and use Operator interface  :

```
package source.main;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import operatorAPI.*;


public class Sum
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        File operatorFile = new File("D:\\");
        URL operatorFilePath = operatorFile.toURL();
        URL[] operatorFilePaths = new URL[]{operatorFilePath};
        ClassLoader operatorsLoader = new URLClassLoader(operatorFilePaths);
        Class currentClass = operatorsLoader.loadClass("math.Plus");

        Operator instance = (Operator) currentClass.newInstance();
        int output = instance.calculate(10,20);
        System.out.println("The result is :" + output);
    }
}
```

I use command line to compile and run the program  .My app work fine but when I try make my main program (source.main.Sum) as a executable jar file named app.jar and run it I get this exception  :

```
NoClassDefFoundError : operatorAPI/Operator
```

I makeand run jar 0file like so  :

```
jar -cvfe app.jar source.main.Sum source/main/Sum.class 
java -cp opr.jar;. -jar app.jar
```

Can anyone tell me why this happend?

Comment: Is your MANIFEST file correct ?

Comment: Yes I think it is .                                                                                             Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_45 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: source.main.Main

Comment: Your error is saying that `operatorAPI/Operator` was used in compile time but its not found at runtime, so there is a problem in your classpath

Comment: is it like Main-Class : <Name of the class from jar containing main method> ?

Comment: @ Maximus Decimus Meridius yes

Comment: @soha your main method is in Sum class so MANIFEST Entry should be like Main-Class: source.main.Sum ?

Comment: @Maximus Decimus Meridius I made a mistake it is Main-Class: source.main.Sum

Comment: @Maximus Decimus Meridius the teacher said that I should load jar file in my sum class but I don't know How to do that ?

Comment: @soha run your jar like : java -jar app.jar from the location where it is present along with the opr.jar

Comment: I do it but didn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89577/discussion-between-maximus-decimus-meridius-and-soha).